# How to get every first result of select query in loop iterating over array of strings?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (e.g. `Users`) in PostgreSQL database. Its size is relatively large (ca. 4 GB of data) and I would like to get a table/result consisting of single rows fulfilling the `select` query. This query shall be executed for each element in an array of strings (couple dozens of elements).

Example single select for one element:

`SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE "Surname" LIKE 'Smith%' LIMIT 1`

Value between `'` and `%'` should be an element of input array.

EDIT: It doesn't matter for me whether I get record no. 1 or 2 for `LIKE 'Smith%'`

How can I achieve this? 
I tried to append query results to some array variable within `FOREACH` loop but with no success.

Example source table:

```
| Id    | Name      | Surname   |
|----   |--------   |---------- |
| 1     | John      | Smiths    |
| 2     | Adam      | Smith     |
| 3     | George    | Kowalsky  |
| 4     | George    | Kowalsky  |
| 5     | Susan     | Connor    |
| 6     | Clare     | Connory   |
| 7     | Susan     | Connor    |
```

And for  `['Smith', 'Connor']` the output is:

```
| Id | Name  | Surname |
|----|-------|---------|
| 1  | John  | Smiths  |
| 5  | Susan | Connor  |
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `limit 1`?

Comment: @DanBracuk I'd like to get only first record fulfilling the query, thus I tried to use `LIMIT`

Comment: First record based on what?  Using `limit` without an `order by` rarely if ever makes sense.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter for me whether it's record no. 1 or 2 for `LIKE 'Smith%'`. I just want only one for each `LIKE`

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres you can use the `ANY` operator to compare a single value to all values of an array. This also works with together with the `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Users" 
WHERE "Surname" like ANY (array['Smith%', 'Connor%'])
```

Note that `LIKE` is case sensitive, if you don't want that, you can use `ILIKE`

Answer (score -1):

This will show you the logic.  Syntax is up to you.

```
where 1 = 2 
start of loop
or surname like 'Array Element goes here%'
end of loop
```